# Efficiently find prime numbers in range close to 10^9

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Range is [10^9-10^6 tiill 10^9]. I've tried all I could find and think off - precomputation with Sieve of Eratosthenes and precheck with Fermat's Primality Test. But still could not get it done in less than 1 minute.

Comment: Sieve is the best. have you tried running it with pypy ? and can you show us your code? maybe you're doing something bad.

Comment: Why do you care about the 1 minute mark?

Comment: Sounds like project euler type stuff lol

Answer (score 2):

Because the range is only 10^6. What I think is that Sieve shouldn't perform so bad.
First generate all prime numbers between 1 and 10^5 (because 10^5 squared is 10^10, and the maximum number is 10^9).
 And then use sieve as follows :
 
Create an array of size 10^6, where index i means, number 10^9-10^6+i, and then use your prime list to cross out all the non-primes.
While using Sieve, of course you should cross out all the even numbers, initially and then you only have nearly 5000 primes in range 2 to 10^5. So overall it's roughly 10^3*10^6 which is 10^9 steps, which doesn't seems extremely complex, running time for Modern Processors.

Comment: Why 10^3*10^6? Seems very pessimistic.

Comment: I ran the simple code of a loop running 10^9 times in C++, and here is the result. link : https://postimg.org/image/kzoysp4lf/ .

Comment: Is that supposed to be a reply to me? It doesn't address what I said.

Comment: I have AMD A8-6410 processor which has a cock frequency of 2.0 - 2.8 GHz, and that's bad. i3 series processors have better performance, so I don't think it will take much time to execute the above program on such processors, maybe slowness of python is an issue. Otherwise 1 minute is also not that bad. You do it once and save in a file for future uses.. :-)

Comment: 1 minute seems very pessimistic, because maybe he wants to add this functionality for different end points of range but same length which is 10^6, in a prime calculator, so he will need to do this efficiently and dynamically as well, 1 minute may be too much for user, if something better can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

This takes less than a second:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def primegen(start=0): # stackoverflow.com/a/20660551
...     if start <= 2: yield 2    # prime (!) the pump
...     if start <= 3: yield 3    # prime (!) the pump
...     ps = primegen()           # sieving primes
...     p = next(ps) and next(ps) # first sieving prime
...     q = p * p; D = {}         # initialization
...     def add(m, s):            # insert multiple/stride
...         while m in D: m += s  #   find unused multiple
...         D[m] = s              #   save multiple/stride
...     while q <= start:         # initialize multiples
...         x = (start // p) * p  #   first multiple of p
...         if x < start: x += p  #   must be >= start
...         if x % 2 == 0: x += p #   ... and must be odd
...         add(x, p+p)           #   insert in sieve
...         p = next(ps)          #   next sieving prime
...         q = p * p             #   ... and its square
...     c = max(start-2, 3)       # first prime candidate
...     if c % 2 == 0: c += 1     # must be odd
...     while True:               # generate infinite list
...         c += 2                #   next odd candidate
...         if c in D:            #   c is composite
...             s = D.pop(c)      #     fetch stride
...             add(c+s, s)       #     add next multiple
...         elif c < q: yield c   #   c is prime; yield it
...         else: # (c == q)      #   add p to sieve
...             add(c+p+p, p+p)   #     insert in sieve
...             p = next(ps)      #     next sieving prime
...             q = p * p         #     ... and its square
...
>>> ps = primegen(10**9-10**6)
>>> p = next(ps)
>>> result = []
>>> while p < 10**9:
...     result.append(p)
...     p = next(ps)
...
>>> print len(result)
47957
```

See https://programmingpraxis.com/2015/07/31/incremental-sieve-of-eratosthenes/ for a description.

Answer (score 1):

This runs for me in about 28 seconds on a macbook pro. The primes you want are in `primes`

```
import math 

def isPrime(n, primes):
   limit = int(math.sqrt(n))
   for i in primes:
      if i > limit:
         return True
      if n % i == 0:
         return False
   return True

low_primes = [2]
for i in range(3, 10**5, 2):
   if isPrime(i, low_primes):
      low_primes.append(i)

primes = []
for i in range(10**9-10**6 + 1, 10**9, 2):
   if isPrime(i, low_primes):
      primes.append(i)
```

Comment: @DanD. Your post says between 10e9-10e6 to 10e9 meaning a range of 10e6.  Considering there are about 78,000 primes below 10e6, this seems reasonable.

Comment: `47957` is exactly right for the number of primes between `10^9 - 10^6` and `10^9`. (Tested with GP/Pari, using `primepi(10^9) - primepi(10^9 - 10^6)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I'll check your answers later, now figured out how to do that myself - applied there the methods in reversed order - first Fermat, then Eratosphen. Takes 2-3 seconds.

```
n = 999000000
#n = 1  # should be 78499
m = n + 1000000


def eratosphene_filter(sorted_array_of_odd):
    biggest = sorted_array_of_odd[-1]
    smallest = sorted_array_of_odd[0]
    mapping ={i:True for i in sorted_array_of_odd}
    for i in range(3, int(biggest**0.5)+1, 2):
        j = nearest_from_bottom = (smallest // i) * i
        while j < biggest:
            if i!=j and j in mapping:
                mapping[j] = False
            j += i

    result = []
    for k,v in mapping.items():
        if v:
            result.append(k)
    return sorted(result)


def fermat_check(x, d=2):
    return pow(d, x-1, x) == 1


def primes_sieve(lower,top):
    if lower < 3:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        lower = 3

    all_numbers_in_range = range(lower if lower % 2 != 0 else lower + 1, top, 2)
    print(len(all_numbers_in_range))
    probably_primes = list(filter(fermat_check, all_numbers_in_range))
    print(len(probably_primes))
    print(probably_primes[:5],'...',probably_primes[-5:])

    primes_for_sure = list(eratosphene_filter(probably_primes))
    print(len(primes_for_sure))
    for i in  primes_for_sure:
        yield i


found_primes = list(primes_sieve(n, m))

print(found_primes[:5],'...',found_primes[-5:])

print(len(found_primes))
```